# If my question is related to many areas, which community should I choose?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question which involves many different areas. For example, it contains encryption, which should belong in [Information Security](//security.stackexchange.com), math principles, which should belong in [Mathematics](//math.stackexchange.com), and Python implementation, which should belong in [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com).

In which community should I choose to post this question?

In addition, it is difficult to break up the question, because without one part, the other parts can not be described properly.

Comment: For me, "it is difficult to separate question" has never been a reason not to try to break a question down into simpler parts to ask them separately.  Whatever you do, don't cross-post the same question to >1 sites.

Comment: If your question involves all of that, it might be too broad, and it might be a good idea to figure out how to identify a more narrowly focused question you can ask.  Without more details about the nature of your question, I find it hard to give a more concrete suggestion.

Comment: Please [edit] this post to contain the actual question. Then we have more info to give you the answers you seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without access to your actual question this is pretty hard to answer, but you should definitely be able to split up your question to cater for the specific sites:

Security:

> Is using [mathematical function] to do [X] cryptographically secure?

Math:

> Is doing [X] to perform [Y] the correct implementation of [mathematical function]?

Implementation:

> Is [code] the correct implementation of [mathematical function] in [language]?

And in that order. Don't ask about security or math on Stack Overflow if the question only has to do with the implementation in Python.

Comment: May I add links to one community which point to other parts of problem ?

Comment: And can I use a small list which is same in every part to overview whole problem?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Just edit your question to add clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have already solved this problem. But this problem give me a deep impression. And it is a little bit verbose. However when I read your answer for several times there is some practical idea in my mind. It I think I have already found a way to deal with these kind of problems. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

From what you're telling us, though, I guess you have two questions. One about the mathematics underlying the encryption algorithm. For this, you should look at [Cryptography SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com).

Then there is the implementation - this is for Stack Overflow. Or, if you have working code but want someone to check it, you can post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

That said - **DO NOT** try to implement encryption algorithms and protocols yourself, except for the learning experience!

Implementing encryption algorithms properly is notoriously hard. For example, the memory space used must be cleaned, lest parts of encryption keys remain in memory - available to other programs that use the machine later.
There are also attacks based on the time it takes to calculate something. It is much more complicated than just implementing the algorithm itself.